# Как Игроку обратиться к Карте в игре?

Tags: java, разработка-игр

В игре отрисовка и логика столкновений должны работать за счет этой карты.

Отрисовка идет из класса Game, в котором и лежит эта карта, но мне также нужен к ней доступ из класса Player, как это реализовать? И появился смежный вопрос, как сделать одну общую переменную для нескольких классов?

Может как-то вынести это в глобальную переменную, как статик какого-то класса, но везде пишут, что глобальные переменные - это плохо, но как тогда это реализовывать без них?

P. S. Карта - это не которая встроенная в язык, а просто массив с "пикселями".

Comment: Плохо, но они есть, и решают вашу задачу

Comment: Можно заинжектить ее в нужный класс сеттером или конструктором и юзать

Comment: В текущий момент, при вызове передвижения игрока из Game я просто пихаю в аргументы функции движения игрока ссылку на эту карту и оно вроде работает. Но это выглядит очень костыльно. `pl[0].move(map, /*some args*/);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глобальные переменные сами по себе не так плохи. Плохо то, что с ними связано - неясный жизненный цикл (кто создает и кто уничтожает), изменения (кто и как меняет их состояние), маскирование зависимостей и неудобство тестирования и пр. Для обычных игр, это все не так критично. Если у вас Карта одна и создается только Игрой и вы гарантируете, что никто ее не изменит неожиданным образом и она будет создана до Игрока и уничтожена после его уничтожения - то все ок - создавайте.

Как вариант, вы можете передавать Игроку ссылку на Карту, чтобы он ее сохранил у себя и мог к ней обращаться когда ему надо.